# Error in Curl when using geojson_read command in R

Tags: r, curl, geojson

My situation is I wrote an R script using a university windows computer and emailed the file to myself. The first and second time I ran the script it was working perfectly, however, I started having the following error on the third run.

I figured out the line causing the problem and the error message:

```
> mapdt <-
> geojson_read("http://maperic.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json",
> what = "sp")
```

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) :
>   Timeout was reached

I have tried http_proxy method in this [link](http://braz.blogspot.com/2007/07/installing-upgrading-r-thru-http-proxy.html), and it was not working properly. I have the same problem in two different network environment.

Thank you.

Comment: Is that the real URL, if so, it doesn't exist

Comment: thanks for solving my problem, just realized the actual link is http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json